# I am able to draw on each ViewController to edit Original ImageView. Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: xcode, drawing, cgcontext

I am working on an animation app and in each other ViewController I can draw on the image that's being currently shown on the original ImageView. Is there any way to fix this?

This is what exactly is happening. I don't really know where in the code the problem exists. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7qWKMugaqeDjGls3zvVitoRmwpOUJFY/view?usp=sharing

Expected to be able to draw only on the DrawingFrame ViewController. However, I can draw on every single ViewController in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would appear to be that your gesture recognizer is still operational, even though you’ve presented another view on top of the current one.

This is a bit unusual. Usually when you present a view like that, the old one (and its gesture recognizers) are removed from the view hierarchy. I’m guessing that you’re just sliding this second view on top of the other. There are a few solutions:

- One solution would be to make sure to define this new view such that (a) it accepts user interaction; and (b) write code so that it handles those gestures. That will avoid having the view behind it picking up those gestures.
- Another solution is to disable your gesture recognizer recognizer when the menu view is presented, and re-enable it when the menu is dismissed.
- The third solution is to change how you present that menu view, making sure you remove the current view from the view hierarchy when you do so. A standard `show`/`present` transition generally does this, though, so we may need to see how you’re presenting this menu view to comment further.

---

That having been said, a few unrelated observations:

- you should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`;
- rather than

  ```
  if pencil.eraser == true { ... }
  ```

  you can

  ```
  if pencil.eraser { ... }
  ```
- I’d suggest giving the `pencil` a computed property:

  ```
  var color: UIColor { return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: opacity) }
  ```

  Then you can just refer to `pencil.color`;
- property names should start with lowercase letter; and
- `drawingFrame` is a confusing name, IMHO, because it’s not a “frame”, but rather likely a `UIImageView`. I’d call it `drawingImageView` or something like that.

Yielding:

```
func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
    guard let pencil = pencil else { return }

    //begins current context (and defer the ending of the context)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingImageView.bounds.size, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

    //where to draw
    drawingImageView.image?.draw(in: drawingImageView.bounds)
    //saves context
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    //drawing the line
    context.move(to: fromPoint)
    context.addLine(to: toPoint)
    context.setLineCap(.round)

    if pencil.eraser {
        //Eraser
        context.setBlendMode(.clear)
        context.setLineWidth(10)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    } else {
        //opacity, brush width, etc.
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        context.setLineWidth(pencil.pencilWidth)
        context.setStrokeColor(pencil.color.cgColor)
    }

    context.strokePath()

    //storing context back into the imageView
    drawingImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

Or, even better, retire `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` altogether and use the modern [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer):

```
func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
    guard let pencil = pencil else { return }

    drawingImageView.image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: drawingImageView.bounds.size).image { _ in
        drawingImageView.image?.draw(in: drawingImageView.bounds)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: toPoint)
        path.lineCapStyle = .round

        if pencil.eraser {
            path.lineWidth = 10
            UIColor.white.setStroke()
        } else {
            path.lineWidth = pencil.pencilWidth
            pencil.color.setStroke()
        }

        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

For more information on [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer), see the “Drawing off-screen” section of WWDC 2018 [Image and Graphics Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219).

As an aside, once you get this problem behind you, you might want to revisit this “stroke from point a to point b and re-snapshot” logic to capture an array of points and build a path from a whole series, and don’t re-snapshot ever point, but only after a whole bunch have been added. This snapshotting process is slow and you’re going to find that the UX stutters a bit more than it needs. I personally re-snapshot after 100 points or so (at which point the amount of time to restroke the whole path is slow enough that it’s not much faster than the snapshot process, so if I snapshot and restart the path from where I left off, it then speeds up again).

But you say:

> Expected to be able to draw only on the DrawingFrame ViewController. However, I can draw on every single ViewController in my app.

The above should draw only the `image` of `drawingImageView` and the stroke from `fromPoint` to `toPoint`. Your problem about drawing on “every single ViewController” rests elsewhere. We’d really need to see how precisely you are presenting this menu scene.

Comment: Thank you sorry about the poor coding practices I have just started working in Xcode. Yeah the problem is still occurring and I don't really understand what is going on. I store the image from the ImageView into an image, so maybe that's where it occurs......Idk...I might just use the UIGraphicsImageRenderer and hope it fixes my problem. Thank you a lot for the help/tips though.

Comment: I posted a video hopefully making it more clear what's happening. I still don't know where this bug is occuring

Comment: The second one worked (Solution B)! Thank you so much. I didn't have a gesture recognizer which was one of my problems probably. But I ended up just overriding every touchedBegan,touchesEnded,etc function in every ViewController and setting the ones that shouldn't draw to just return nothing.